# Changing IF statements, saving some code

Tags: if-statement, vhdl

Hello friends and pro programmers, im new to this world of VHDL and i have this question.
i want to make this:

```
   if counter >= 0 and counter <=95 then
    aux_Hs <= '0';
   else
    aux_Hx <= '1';
   end if;
```

in something like this:

```
   aux_Hs <= (counter >= 0 and counter <=95);
```

this **error** shows up:

> Line 73. Type of aux_Hs is incompatible with type of and.

`aux_Hs` is a signal `STD_Logic`.

is there some way to **save** the **IF statements? a pseudo " ? : " instruction?**.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are your two code examples correct? They seem to do opposite things

Answer (score 4):

As concurrent code, without VHDL-2008:

```
   aux_Hs <= '1' when (counter >= 0 and counter <=95) else '0' ;
```

With VHDL-2008:

```
   aux_Hs <= counter ?>= 0 and counter ?<=95 ;
```

Comment: u can use them inside a process?, from what i was told, inside a process u need to use IF, and outside a process u can do "when" statements.

Comment: That's a good rule.  The line of code that Jim wrote above was meant to execute outside a process.  The code that you had in your initial example belongs inside a clocked process.

Comment: Prior to VHDL-2008, conditional assignments, aka "when", were required to be outside of a process.  With VHDL-2008, you can also use them inside a process.  The 2008 code in the 2nd code snippet can be used anywhere (assuming the tool supports it).  Keep in mind for synthesis much of VHDL-2008 is still on the bleeding edge - use when you have a compelling need, but always test and report bugs - this is how we get new features prioritized.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this inside a process, you can save a line of code like this:

```
aux_Hs <= '0';
if not (counter >= 0 and counter <=95) then
   aux_Hx <= '1';
end if;
```

Or you can use VHDL-2008 (look for the switches on your compiler and log a bug if VHDL2008 is not supported!) which allows conditional assigment inside processes:

```
aux_Hs <= '0' when (counter >= 0 and counter <=95) else '1' ;
```